# Timeout performing SCAN

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

getting "Timeout performing SCAN, inst: 0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 1, qu=1, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0/1, in=0/0" while asking for keys on redis

Have no idea why it is happening ?

```
public void DeleteKeys(string pattern)
{
    try
    {
        EndPoint[] endPoints = m_connectionMultiplexer.GetEndPoints();
        foreach (EndPoint endPoint in endPoints)
        {
            IServer server = m_connectionMultiplexer.GetServer(endPoint);
            RedisValue redisValue = pattern;
            IEnumerable<RedisKey> redisKeys = server.Keys(0, redisValue);
            foreach (RedisKey redisKey in redisKeys)
            {
                m_connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase().KeyDelete(redisKey);
            }  
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        m_logger.Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting exactly the same message `'Timeout performing SCAN, inst: 1, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 7, qu=0, qs=7, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=0/0'`

Comment: @Vitalik, seems like Marc is on it. I do FlushAll for now since my use case is project re-initialization and not deletion of specific pattern of keys YET.

Comment: Not sure if that matters but the numbers changed today: `'Timeout performing SCAN, inst: 1, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 15, qu=0, qs=15, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=0/0'`

Answer (score 2):

That *particular* combination of status flags tells me that one command (specifically: `scan`) is stuck in the unsent queue, and while it knows a writer is needed, no writer is active. Do you have a full repro? This is probably better raised as a bug.

Comment: It happens all the time, how do i collect logs for the bug ?

Comment: @eugene well, what you've posted is already *quite* helpful, in that I can narrow it down to writer activation. If you had, say, a console exe that reliably reproduced it that would be awesome. However, it isn't something I've seen. Are you using vLatest?

Comment: i've been using Win redis port 2.8.12 the latest 1.0.333, though somehow dll shows up as 1.0.316.0 maybe wrong package for 1.0.333 nuget ? If you don't find the issue I can mail you some basic solution but you did not get my last mail ( maybe because of some spam filter )